# File download in angular js SPA with ASP.net web API not working properly?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented web application by using angular js and WEB API using asp.net.
There i used ContentDisposition to return file name as below WEB API controller method.

```
try
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + fileName;

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
                        file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
                        ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);

                        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
                        httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes.ToArray());
                        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", fileName);
                        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "" + fileName + "";

                        httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                        return httpResponseMessage;
                    }
                }
            }
            return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "File not found.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
        }
```

but when trying to access x-filename name from client side it not exsists in there. angular code is shown below.

```
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: common.serviceUrl(config.apiServices.usermanuals),
            params: { manualId: manualId },
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            headers = headers();
            //var test = headers('Content-Disposition');
            var filename = headers['x-filename'];
            var contentType = headers['content-type'];

            var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
            try {
                var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
                linkElement.setAttribute("download", filename);

                var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
                    "view": window,
                    "bubbles": true,
                    "cancelable": false
                });
                linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
            } catch (ex) {
                console.log(ex);
            }
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

returning headers shown below

[image]

file name is undefined
How can i access ContentDisposition from here. pls help

Thanks

Comment: Be sure to include `x-filename` in the  [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) header.

Comment: @georgeawg Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added below code into controller and it solved the problem.

exposedHeaders: "x-filename"

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "x-filename")]
```